# add canvas if height < X

Tags: php, javascript, html, gd

Sorry my lousy english, I'm sleepy and struggling with this about 3 days ago.
I'm using "slideViewerPro 1.5" to display an image gallery (PHP + JS).
However, this js script forces me to have all the images at the same size.
So, when I have a vertical picture, I would like to add some white canvas to it so it won't get distorted.
I've tried offline, using Irfanview. Won't work.
I've tried hacking up some GD and PHP scripts. Won't work either.
Messing around the slideViewerPro javascript source... neither.
Also... I've read this about 20 times, and still can't figure out if GD is a proper solution.
http://www.rubblewebs.co.uk/imagemagick/GDexamples.php

Can someone enlight me please?!

Comment: Can you show us an example page, or the code?

Comment: Place the mouse over the thumbnail, it will give you the widht and height.

Comment: I'm now trying this:
Get the image width; If less than 550, add canvas to the left (since the frame is always 550x325. But GD and I don't do well :)

Comment: HMM... this might work, but instead of multiple pictures, only one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933170/create-a-picture-with-gd-containing-other-images

Comment: Try that as well, basically the point is to use 2 images, one blank, and copying from one to the other, larger image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps with using GD:

```
$im=imagecreatefrompng($filename);
$width=imagesx($im);
$height=imagesy($im);
$newwidth = 550;
$newheight = 325;
$output = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
imagecopymerge($output, $im, ($width<550?550-$width:0), ($height<325?325-$height:0), 0, 0, $width, $height,0);
imagepng($output);
imagedestroy($output);
imagedestroy($im);
```

`$filename` is the filename, and then we create a blank image of size 550x325 and paste the image onto the new canvas

Comment: I'm getting a black canvas/picture. (had to change png to jpeg) this makes difference?

Comment: `$im=imagecreatefrompng($filename);` uses png, but you can change it to whatever and it shouldn't make a difference... I am not an expert with GD, but I have one function like this in a script I am using to shift an image to the right for printing.

Comment: Can't get it to work. Change $output to $im and yes, I get the original image. Something's going on on imagecopymerge :|

Comment: maybe just do imagecopy instead of imagecopymerge and take the "0" for the last variable off?

Comment: Woo hooo :) Thanks Tim! it's working: check it @ segmentoponto4.com.pt/wp (Projectos)