# PHP GD - resizing image frame/canvas but not the actual image

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

I have an image with size 88x31 and would like to make it 100x100 without resizing the actual image but only its canvas/frame, maybe by copying it in the center of the new blank white image with 100x100 size. Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Don't revert to reinventing the wheel, use existing code: https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine, but if you insist, there are a plethora of similar questions on SO that have been answered already.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a picture with GD containing other images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933170/create-a-picture-with-gd-containing-other-images)

Comment: the problem with Imagine is namespace support which my PHP has not at the moment and I don't want to upgrade just yet but thanks.

Comment: Don't resist the future! Upgrade! ;-) But seriously, this problem has been solved more times than Justin Bieber has fans. If SO doesn't suffice to you, have look on Google http://www.google.fi/search?q=gd+wrapper+php or the PHP manual page for `imagecopy` http://fi.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php

Comment: yep, I got it now, thanks nikc.org

Answer (score 10):

The correct method is to create a new image and then copy the old image into the middle of it (assuming the starting image is is a JPEG and smaller than 100x100):

```
$oldimage = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
$oldw = imagesx($oldimage);
$oldh = imagesy($oldimage);

$newimage = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 100); // Creates a black image

// Fill it with white (optional)
$white = imagecolorallocate($newimage, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($newimage, 0, 0, $white);

imagecopy($newimage, $oldimage, (100-$oldw)/2, (100-$oldh)/2, 0, 0, $oldw, $oldh);
```